# What does 'project-plugging' mean here? Also can any other constructions be formed using '~plugging'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Guy Branum

> Awarding points for name-dropping, project-plugging and flirting with the host, the former Chelsea Lately writer's monthly Talk Show: The Game Show competition elevates self-promotion to performance art (think Graham Norton meets @midnight). Live, "Branum absolutely does not give a fuck," marvels ASpecialThing Records co-founder Ryan McManemin, whose label releases Branum's debut, Effable, this coming year. "His comedy is subversive, intelligent and filthy. One of the most unique voices in comedy today, both literally and figuratively." Up next: writing full-time for Comedy Central's Victorian faux-?
>   reality show Another Period.

The above text is directly quoted from : http://www.laweekly.com/arts/10-comedy-acts-to-watch-in-2015-5268608

Comment: Plug means "promote in public given the opportunity", e.g. an author who has just released a new book may "plug" the book while being interviewed on the radio. X-plugging can be formed if you mean promoting in this way.

Comment: A similar term is *shilling* which often has a connotation of doing the promotion surreptitiously.

Answer (score 3):

[To plug](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plug) can be defined as:

> 9 a recommendation or other favourable mention of a product, show, etc, as on television, on radio, or in newspapers

(Collins Dictionary Online)

So this means that Branum encourages self promotion by recommending one's own projects.

Show-plugging, film-plugging, book-plugging, church-plugging, recipe-plugging, and many more would be understood.  It's somewhat informal and it's entertainment industry jargon, but it's commonly enough used in reporting on the entertainment industry that it can be understood by those outside that industry.